# Hash partitioning with 4 columns in hana

Tags: partitioning, hana

i have table with 4 primary key fields and i have to perform partitioning.

Is there any difference in performance if use  single column instead of using 3 or 4 column in hash partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Number of partitioning will not impact the performance.it will use hash function to figure out the partition where data is stored.